# wfs layer features not fully loaded in the map

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, geoext

i am a bit new to openlayers 2. i have a layer of roads for a city that i want to loaded to the map using wfs protocol. the layer is huge and it does not fully displayed on the map

this is the code i am having

```
proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],   
                    url: GEO_SERVER_URL + "/wfs",
                    version: "1.1.0",
                    featureType: "roads",
                    featureNS: "http://roads.com",
                    srsName: "EPSG:3997"
                })
            })
```

your help is extremely appreciated

Comment: can you check in firebug are all the features arriving at the browser

Comment: i got this message Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES --- so how to avoid this kind of error

Comment: ask for fewer features or make your browser bigger